# For what values of m,n does Km,n have an eulerian trail?

Tags: graph-theory

I have been thinking about this question and figured out that when m and n are even that they have an eulerian trail, Other than this are there cases where m and n have an eulerian trail and if so why?

Comment: Do you know the very simple requirement that Euler discovered for a graph to have an Eulerian trail? It is _very easy_ to count the degrees of vertices in a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: A far-fetched example: what happens if $m=n=1$?

Comment: @bof You cannot have that $m=n=1$ because an Eulerian graph has to be connected and each degree has to be even.

Comment: A Eulerian **trail** does not have to return to its starting point, so the graph can have two vertices of odd degree. A Eulerian **circuit** is a **closed** Eulerian trail (returns to its starting point), and requires the graph to have no vertices of odd degree. You wrote "trail" not "circuit" in your question. Did you mean circuit?